# Pasando valor entre inputs con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, keypressevent

estoy algo confundido, intento pasar el value de un input a otro mientras estoy escribiendo en el input, mas sin embargo al consultar encuentro funciones con JavaScript y JQuery que al aplicarlas, no se que sucede que no me ha funcionado, tengo correctamente incluido tanto el Script de JQuery como el link al script de javascript donde hago la función, incluso el evento 'keyup' al mostrar por consola si me muestra, pero cuando termino de asignarle el valor y hacer la prueba escribiendo no funciona. Agradezco si me pueden echar una mano.
Este es el códgo HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" value="" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura1"> 
    </td>
    <td><h3>*</h3></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura2"></td>
</tr>
```

Intento que el input "txtAltura2" tome el valor de "txtAltura1" mientras estoy escribiendo. Tengo actualmente este script.

```
var txtAlura = document.getElementById('txtAltura1');

txtAlura.addEventListener('keyup', (event) =>{
    var txtValor = event.path[0].value;
    document.getElementById('txtAltura2').innerHTML = txtValor;
});
```

Sin embargo al recargar la pagina no me funciona, no se copia el contenido. Descargué desde la pagina oficial de JQuery la versión.

```
<!-- Latest Compiled JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Agradezco sus ayudas.
[Actualizada] - Muchas gracias por las respuestas, la pregunta fue solucionada mas sin embargo hay un error o no se si esto puede afectar mas adelante a mi aplicación, es como un bloqueo o algo así me aparece en la consola al cargar la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar el evento oninput que se dispara cada ves que escribes una letra.
también te recomiendo quitar el value=""  ya que a veces deja forzado el value y da problemas

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("txtAltura1").value;
  document.getElementById("txtAltura2").value = x;
}
```

```html
<!-- JQUERY NO ES NECESARIO PARA ESTE EJEMPLO -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura1" oninput="myFunction()"> 
    </td>
    <td><h3>*</h3></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, usé el link al JQuery que me diste y seguí tu recomendación. Ya se solucionó mi problema y ahora si funciona.. Voy a modificar la pregunta porque al recargar la pagina me está apareciendo un error o algo quizas de pronto sabes tambien.

Comment: super!, aunque si es ese el caro, te recomiendo generar una nueva pregunta. saludos

Comment: @JhonnattanRivera creo que sería muy conveniente le indicaras al OP que para ninguna parte de tu solución se ocupa JQuery por tanto invocarlo es innecesario

Comment: ok, modificare la respuesta. gracias ;)

Answer (score 2):

El único problema que había era que no seleccionabas el `value` del input. Recuerda que para modificar el contenido del input, es necesario modificar su value. Esto funciona mejor.

```js
var txtAltura = document.getElementById('txtAltura1');

txtAltura.addEventListener('keyup', () =>{
    var txtValor = txtAltura.value;
    document.getElementById('txtAltura2').value = txtValor;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" value="" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura1"> 
    </td>
    <td><h3>*</h3></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: +1 esta es la respuesta mas simple que resuelve el problema raíz y que lo explica

Answer (score 0):

- Para agregar texto a un input se usa la propiedad [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) en lugar de [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- No entiendo para que esto: `event.path[0].value;`, cuando lo único que necesitas es obtener al segundo input y asignarle el valor del primero

```html
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" value="" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura1"> 
        </td>
        <td><h3>*</h3></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Altura (m)" class="mt-2 form-control" id="txtAltura2"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <script>
      let txtAltura1 = document.getElementById('txtAltura1');
      let txtAltura2 = document.getElementById('txtAltura2');
      
      txtAltura1.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        txtAltura2.value = txtAltura1.value
      });
    </script>
```

Como extra no mezcles código de JavaScript dentro de las etiquetas HTML, mejor recuperalas en alguna variable y dales un *listener* en el evento deseado, además esto es algo muy simple no ocupas de JQuery

**Referencia**

- [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el evento onchange

```
<input type="text" onchange="passTo(this)"  id="txtAltura1">

function passTo(objetoinput)
 {
    document.getElementById("txtAltura2").value = objetoinput.value

 }
```